# Can I run a .NET 6.0 service with .NET 8.0 runtime?

Tags: c#, .net-core, version

I developed a .NET 6.0 app. The computer (raspberry 3) where this service will run has .NET 8.0 runtime.

When I try to run the application with `dotnet service.dll`, this message appears:

> You must install or update .NET to run this application.
>
> App: /home/stationpi/Rpi3Gateway/RpiGateway.dll
> Architecture: arm
> Framework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '6.0.0' (arm)
> .NET location: /opt/dotnet/
>
> The following frameworks were found:
> 8.0.3 at [/opt/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>
> Learn more:
> https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed
>
> To install missing framework, download:
> https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=6.0.0&arch=arm&rid=linux-arm&os=raspbian.11

I can't run services developed in previous version of .NET Core?

Obs: the strangest thing is that when I published the same code for linux-arm64 (raspberry 4), this problem didn't happen

Answer (score 0):

I understood my mistake. In the linux-arm64 publish settings I selected the "Deployment mode" option as "Self-Contained".

When I created another profile, I set this option to "Framework-dependent", which is why when running, it questioned version 6.0.0 of dotnet core.

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about dotnet core then you can run the services of .Net 6.0 with .Net 8.0 you just have to install the .Net 8.0 necessary [SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/8.0) and after that follow these steps:

1. find bin and obj folder in the project directory.
2. delete the both folder bin and obj.
3. run the command **dotnet clean** and **dotnet build** in your **VScode** if your using another IDE then clean and build your project accordingly.
4. run the project by **dotnet run** command if any issue persist then run the code in debug mode and resolve it accordingly.